# flutterwave creating webview issue in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutterwave

Thanks in advance,
i am facing this issue in my flutter project. project received from my client.

my flutter version "2.8.1" latest and Dart "2.15.1"

```
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)


.........   


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 38s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and that is in my pubspec.yaml file.
these are all libs used  in project

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
  get: ^4.6.1
  http: ^0.13.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.11
  flutter_paystack: ^1.0.4+1
  flutterwave: ^1.0.1
```

Comment: Please try to update your compileSdkVersion 31 in app/build.gradle file

Comment: already tried but same issue